# Regex should not match for two or more consecutive dashes

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex:

```
\p{Alpha}[\p{Alnum}-]+\p{Alnum}
```

With this, the text should start with an alpha character and could be followed by alphanumerics and dashes.

But I don t want to have two or more consecutive dashes. What is the right regex that I can use for this case?

Thanks to all

Frank

Comment: Which tool/platform/language are you using? Probably Java?

Comment: yes, i'm using java! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may consider this regex solution:

```bash
^\p{Alpha}\p{Alnum}*(?:-\p{Alnum}+)*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kBjSRm/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `\p{Alpha}`: Match an alphabet
- `\p{Alnum}*`: Match 0 or more alphanumeric characters
- `(?:-\p{Alnum}+)*`: Match `-` followed by 1+ of alphanumeric characters. Repeat this group 0 or more times
- `$`: End

Comment: Nice! I note this won't match a string which ends with a dash (which I think is valid from OP's description). Of course appending a final `-*` would fix this: `^\p{Alpha}\p{Alnum}*(?:-\p{Alnum}+)*-*$`

Comment: A `-*` in the end would match `ab11---` and I believe OP wants only single `-` in the middle of the string.

Comment: D'oh, of course, you're right!

Comment: I suppose a `^\p{Alpha}\p{Alnum}*(?:-\p{Alnum}+)*-?$` if they wanted to include cases which ended in a single `-` ?

Comment: Yes, I don't want the dash at the start or at the end of the string. So, perfect solution for me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -2):

Probably this will work

\p{Alpha}[\p{Alnum}-]+(?!-)\p{Alnum}

In this pattern, (?!-) is the negative lookahead assertion that ensures there is no dash immediately following the previous match.

Comment: Lookahead is redundant in this expression. It wouldn't filter out any strings.

Comment: Consider testing your answers before posting. This can be done on regex101.com, for example.